# Grunt jshint disable Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I am using `grunt-contrib-jshint` and it finds the following error in my JS file:

```
line 5   col 70  Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
```

I know the reason of this error, but all I want is to disable it. Looking [here](http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression) it looks like I can either use `no-cond-assign` to 0 in my `jshintrc` or by adding `-W084 : true`  in my options.

The problem is that the first solution ended up in a corrupted jshintrc and the second one does not solve the problem. Another option is to add `-W022 : true` (which solution I found in the comments) also does not work.

Comment: This solution:

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474794/296373][1]

work for me. Try.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474794/296373

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ignore](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/wiki/Documentation#ignore) pragma to skip this line:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
if(this = Infinity)
/* jshint ignore:end */
  {
  return;
  }
```